# What is the correct way to share same code between several viewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, inheritance

I have several view controllers (or to be specific, tableview controllers), and all these view controllers use the same view (a loading view) that can be displayed while data access is running.

Currently, I have the same code in all these view controllers:

```
// Loading the loading view
NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"loadingView" owner:nil options:nil];
loadingView = [nibContents lastObject];

[self.view addSubview:loadingView];
```

I also use a toast view for that displays success or errors after operation within the controller.

My question is, what is the proper way to avoid code copy/pasting?

I have tried categories :
Doesn't seem to work since I can't store the reference to the loading view.

I also have tried inheritance, but without much success (the child controller doesn't recognise the properties (loading view) of the parent view controller).

Could you lead me to the right way to do this?
I'm using a storyboard and NIB files for the specific views (loading and toasts).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create another class with NSObject on that classes. For example, Class Car contains of objects Tire, Steering, Machine, Seat, Window.
when you call that class like Car *carObject = [Car alloc]init];    carObject.Tire to get the tire reference.

Comment: @HotLicks You definitely know the answer, I think I don't.

Comment: @Bejibun it means that I'll still have to call the methods. Cannot it be done automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by calling the methods? you are not calling the method, but you call the class to get the object of that class. If you want to share a method and not class, try to use global function.     +(void)myMethod instead of -(void)myMethod

Comment: I will still have to do some stuffs like :
[myNewClass initLoadingView] that will do the code shown in my post,

A call to [myNewClass showView] in the "scrollViewDidScroll" function (for example), and this code will be repeated in the 4 controllers that use the same view at the same moment.

Comment: Apparently someone else thought I didn't know the answer, since they deleted my comment.  (I merely asked how you'd do it for classes that were not view controllers.  Still a valid question, and one you should be able to answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried categories : Doesn't seem to work since I can't store the reference to the loading view.

View controller categories, or alternatively class methods on the views you are displaying, are the best way to deal with this problem.

You can use associated objects to keep a reference to the view that is being displayed. If you're wary of those, a `static` variable can be used to give persistent storage without requiring a property or instance variable. These both assume you will only be showing one loading view or alert view at once, which is to be expected.

For categories you'd define a method like

`-(void)setLoading:(BOOL)loading`

On a view controller. This would have a static variable which referred to the loading view. If you were passing YES, you'd create the view, show it and assign it to the static (if it wasn't already present). If you were passing NO, you'd remove the view and set the static back to nil.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have seen some stuffs about this way to do. I will spend more time on it :-)